# i want to facebook feed development but feed ... customize?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently working under a facebook javascript sdk.
but i am limit => Fixed frame (shape, position)
Javascript sdk, as html or other method I want to create a facebook feed system.
Thank you tell us how or related links.

for example

[image]

Except facebook api that provides access to feeds from Facebook and the Facebook system Is there a way to raise the feed in the form of message I want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on Facebook [Controlling What You See in News Feed](https://www.facebook.com/help/335291769884272/) providing information about that how to change feed. Follow the link and design customize feed.

Comment: thank you your answer, but the answer is not the answer I wanted. I wanted to answer was how to put into the desired shape to automatically feeds from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Built to the conclusion that there is no way except the Facebook api.

Comment: I knew . Only use that only offer or that you need to use the Open Graph